# deSolve: differential equations with two consecutive dynamics

Tags: r, ode, desolve

I am simulating a ring tube with flowing water and a temperature gradient using `deSolve::ode()`. The ring is modelled as a vector where each element has a temperature value and position.

I am modelling the heat diffusion formula:

1)[image: Heat diffusion]

But I'm struggling with also moving the water along the ring. In theory, it's just about substituting the temperature at the element *i* in the tube vector with that at the element *s* places earlier. Since *s* may not be an integer, it can be separated into the integer part (*n*) and the fractional part (*p*): *s=n+p*. Consequently, the change in temperature due to the water moving becomes:

2)[image: Water flow]

The problem is that *s* equals to the water velocity *v* by the *dt* evaluated at each iteration of the ode solver.

My idea is to treat the phenomenons as additive, that is first computing (1), then (2) and finally adding them together. I'm afraid though about the effect of time. The ode solver with implicit methods decides the time step automatically and scales down linearly the unitary change delta.

My question is whether just returning (1) + (2) in the derivative function is correct or if I should break the two processes apart and compute the derivatives separately. In the second case, what would be the suggested approach?

EDIT:
As by suggestion by @tpetzoldt I tried to implement the water flow using `ReacTran::advection.1D()`. My model has multiple sources of variation of temperature: the spontaneous symmetric heat diffusion; the water flow; a source of heat that is turned on if the temperature near a sensor (placed before the heat source) drops below a lower threshold and is turned off if raises above an upper threshold; a constant heat dispersion determined by a cyclical external temperature.

Below the "Moving water" section there is still my previous version of the code, now substituted by `ReacTran::advection.1D()`.
The `plot_type` argument allows visualizing either a time sequence of the temperature in the water tube ("pipe"), or the temperature sequence at the sensors (before and after the heater).

```
library(deSolve)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(ReacTran)

test <- function(simTime = 5000, vel = 1, L = 500, thresh = c(16, 25), heatT = 25,
                                    heatDisp = .0025,   baseTemp = 15, alpha = .025,
                                    adv_method = 'up', plot_type = c('pipe', 'sensors')) {
    
    plot_type <- match.arg(plot_type)

    thresh <- c(16, 25)

    sensorP <- round(L/2)

    vec <- c(rep(baseTemp, L), 0)

    eventfun <- function(t, y, pars) {

        heat <- y[L + 1] > 0

        if (y[sensorP] < thresh[1] & heat == FALSE) { # if heat is FALSE -> T was above the threshold
            #browser()
            y[L + 1] <- heatT
        }

        if (y[sensorP] > thresh[2] & heat == TRUE) { # if heat is TRUE -> T was below the threshold
            #browser()
            y[L + 1] <- 0
        }

        return(y)
    }

    rootfun <- function (t, y, pars) {

        heat <- y[L + 1] > 0

        trigger_root <- 1

        if (y[sensorP] < thresh[1] & heat == FALSE & t > 1) { # if heat is FALSE -> T was above the threshold
            #browser()
            trigger_root <- 0
        }

        if (y[sensorP] > thresh[2] & heat == TRUE & t > 1) { # if heat is TRUE -> T was below the threshold
            #browser()
            trigger_root <- 0
        }


        return(trigger_root)
    }

    roll <- function(x, n) {
        x[((1:length(x)) - (n + 1)) %% length(x) + 1]
    }

    fun <- function(t, y, pars) {

        v <- y[1:L]

        # Heat diffusion: dT/dt = alpha * d2T/d2X
        d2Td2X <- c(v[2:L], v[1]) + c(v[L], v[1:(L - 1)]) - 2 * v

        dT_diff <- pars * d2Td2X

        # Moving water
        # nS <- floor(vel)
        # pS <- vel - nS
        #
        # v_shifted <- roll(v, nS)
        # nS1 <- nS + 1
        # v_shifted1 <- roll(v, nS + 1)
        #
        # dT_flow <- v_shifted + pS * (v_shifted1 - v_shifted) - v
        dT_flow <- advection.1D(v, v = vel, dx = 1, C.up = v[L], C.down = v[1],
                                                        adv.method = adv_method)$dC

        dT <- dT_flow + dT_diff

        # heating of the ring after the sensor
        dT[sensorP + 1] <- dT[sensorP  + 1] + y[L + 1]

        # heat dispersion
        dT <- dT - heatDisp * (v - baseTemp + 2.5 * sin(t/(60*24) * pi * 2))

        return(list(c(dT, 0)))
    }

    out <- ode.1D(y = vec, times = 1:simTime, func = fun, parms = alpha, nspec = 1,
                                    events = list(func = eventfun, root = T),
                                    rootfunc = rootfun)


    if (plot_type == 'sensors') {

        ## Trend of the temperature at the sensors levels
        out %>%
            {.[,c(1, sensorP + 1, sensorP + 3, L + 2)]} %>%
            as.data.frame() %>%
            setNames(c('time', 'pre', 'post', 'heat')) %>%
            mutate(Amb = baseTemp + 2.5 * sin(time/(60*24) * pi * 2)) %>%
            pivot_longer(-time, values_to = "val", names_to = "trend") %>%
            ggplot(aes(time, val)) +
            geom_hline(yintercept = thresh) +
            geom_line(aes(color = trend)) +
            theme_minimal() +
            theme(panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines")) +
            labs(x = 'time', y = 'T°', color = 'sensor')
    } else {

    ## Trend of the temperature in the whole pipe
    out %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        pivot_longer(-time, values_to = "val", names_to = "x") %>%
        filter(time %in% round(seq.int(1, simTime, length.out = 40))) %>%
        ggplot(aes(as.numeric(x), val)) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = thresh) +
        geom_line(alpha = .5, show.legend = FALSE) +
        geom_point(aes(color = val)) +
        scale_color_gradient(low = "#56B1F7", high = "red") +
        facet_wrap(~ time) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines")) +
        labs(x = 'x', y = 'T°', color = 'T°')
    }
}
```

It's interesting that setting an higher number of segment (`L = 500`) and high speed (`vel = 2`) it's possible to observe a spiking sequence in the post heating sensor. Also, the processing time drastically increases, but more as an effect of increased velocity than due to increased pipe resolution.

[image]

My biggest doubt now is whether `ReacTran::advection.1D()` does make sense in my context since I'm modeling water temperature, while this function seems more related to the concentration of a solute in flowing water.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but things like this can be solved with function `ode.1D` from package **deSolve** and when needed also functions from package **ReacTran**. There is already some material online (package vignettes, papers) and you may also have a look at https://dynamic-r.github.io/

Comment: A good introduction about the "method of lines" (MOL) approach with R/deSolve can be be found the paper about **ReachTran** from Soetaert and Meysman (2012) https://doi.org/10.1016/j.envsoft.2011.08.011

Comment: So that means that simply summing the dT from heat diffusion and water flow would not be correct?

Comment: I suggest to read some material and then to come to a good solution. It may also be possible to discuss it at a particular code example.

Comment: eheh it was a side project and I hoped to be able to solve it fast. Anyway, I get oscillations if the water speed is too fast. I'll look into the matter and if I can't solve it I'll post the code

Comment: This is an interesting case, but it is also somewhat complex. I made small technical edits: libraries,  FALSE/TRUE instead of F/T, but I can't see the oscillations with the plot functions you provided. Anyway, I suggest to re-edit the question back to the original version (the one without code) and then to start a new one with code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean you are not able to reproduce the plot? I just noticed that the default plotting shows temperature along the tube, not in time. The correct call is the following: test(vel = 2, L=500, plot_type = 'sens')

Comment: ((Text subscripts in LaTeX should be done by switching to text mode, `$\Delta T_{\text{diffusion}}$` or for the lazy writer `$\Delta T_{\rm diffusion}$`. Use `\textit` or just `\it` for italics.))

Comment: Thanks for the subscript hint! I didn’t understand what you are referring to for the italics part though, you mean to have italics subscripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like a PDE example with a mobile and a fixed phase. A good introduction about the "method of lines" (MOL) approach with R/deSolve can be be found in the paper about ReachTran from Soetaert and Meysman (2012) [doi.org/10.1016/j.envsoft.2011.08.011](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.envsoft.2011.08.011).

An example PDE can be found at [slide 55 of some workshop slides](https://dynamic-r.github.io/hacking-limnology/#55), more in the teaching package [RTM](https://github.com/dynamic-R/RTM).

R/deSolve/ReacTran tries to make ODEs/PDEs easy, but pitfalls remain. If numerical dispersion or oscillations occur, it can be caused by violating the [Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition).

Comment: eventually I am using ReacTran::advection.1D for the water flow effect. I am not 100% sure of what am I doing, since in my case I don't have a substance with a given concentration dispersed in water, but I'm modelling the water temperature itself. I'll post the code in case you wish to give a look.